# slide up elements in a sequential order

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to `slideUp` elements sequencially, one by one, not asynch.

`block2` should start sliding when `block1` is closed.

`block3` should start sliding when `block2` is closed.

And so on. In reality I have a lot of such elements so any nested syntax (function inside function) is not suitable.

I hope `async await` is the right way but cannot understand fully.

Here is my try:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
close_all();
});
async function close_all(){
  await close1();
  await close2();
  await close3();
}
function close1(){
$('#block1').slideUp();
}
function close2(){
$('#block2').slideUp();
}
function close3(){
$('#block3').slideUp();
}
```

```css
.block{
display:inline-block;
width:14%;
background:gold;
margin:0 9px;
}
#block1{
height:54px;
}
#block2{
height:25px;
}
#block3{
height:72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block' id='block1'>BLOCK 1</div>
<div class='block' id='block2'>BLOCK 2</div>
<div class='block' id='block3'>BLOCK 3</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: I have updated with generic approach, if I found a way to do the same with `await` and `async` I will update again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be using the `on complete` callback that you can use on the [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) method:

```js
$('button').on('click', function()
{
    close_all($(".block"));
});

function close_all(elements, idx=0)
{
    if (idx >= elements.length)
        return;

    let cb = () => close_all(elements, idx + 1);    
    elements.eq(idx).slideUp(2000, cb);
}
```

```css
.block {
  float: left;
  width:14%;
  background:gold;
  margin:0 9px;
}

#block1{
  height:54px;
}

#block2{
  height:25px;
}

#block3{
  height:72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='block' id='block1'>BLOCK 1</div>
<div class='block' id='block2'>BLOCK 2</div>
<div class='block' id='block3'>BLOCK 3</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: much better but what is the starting jumping, just after click

Comment: @qadenza that was related to `display:inline-block` CSS property. I have changed it to `foat:left` for a similar layout. However I can't explain the issue related to using `display:inline-block`.

Comment: @qadenza I also have made a question about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653265/issue-with-displayinline-block-css-property