# Issue with `display:inline-block` CSS property

Tags: jquery, css

I have made recently one answer to another user about a generic method for [JQuery::slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) sequentially multiple items. If you want a reference, you can check it here:

[slide up elements in a sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639862/slide-up-elements-in-a-sequential-order/54639922#54639922)

After come to a solution the `OP` asked me about an **initial jumping effect** that you can observe on the next code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function()
{
    close_all($(".block"));
});

function close_all(elements, idx=0)
{
    if (idx >= elements.length)
        return;

    let cb = () => close_all(elements, idx + 1);    
    elements.eq(idx).slideUp(2000, cb);
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width:14%;
  background:gold;
  margin:0 9px;
}

#block1{
  height:54px;
}

#block2{
  height:25px;
}

#block3{
  height:72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='block' id='block1'>BLOCK 1</div>
<div class='block' id='block2'>BLOCK 2</div>
<div class='block' id='block3'>BLOCK 3</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

After digging a little about it, I have come that this is related to `display:inline-block` property he has over the `.block` elements. For what I have read so far (I'm not experimented on `CSS`) this property it a sort of replacement for `float:left`. So I decided to change the style to use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` and the issue disappear. You can check it on next code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function()
{
    close_all($(".block"));
});

function close_all(elements, idx=0)
{
    if (idx >= elements.length)
        return;

    let cb = () => close_all(elements, idx + 1);    
    elements.eq(idx).slideUp(2000, cb);
}
```

```css
.block {
  float: left;
  width:14%;
  background:gold;
  margin:0 9px;
}

#block1{
  height:54px;
}

#block2{
  height:25px;
}

#block3{
  height:72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='block' id='block1'>BLOCK 1</div>
<div class='block' id='block2'>BLOCK 2</div>
<div class='block' id='block3'>BLOCK 3</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Anyone has idea why the issue appears when we use `display:inline-block`?

Comment: for more accurate explanation, there is the overflow:hidden added to your element making the baseline to the bottom and no more the text .. and since the alignment is baseline, you have this issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: added another duplicate with more details